Arranging $$ distinct $2$-square dominoes on a horizontal strip of $2n$ squares
Suppose a horizontal strip of $2n$ squares. We want to count the number of ways of arranging $k$ distinct $2$-square dominoes on this strip.
The dominoes should not overlap, and $2k\leq2n$.
One could try placing the $k$ dominoes one by one i.e $(2n-1)$ possible ways for the first domino, etc, using the product rule. But this fails because the chosen position for, say the first domino, determines the number of adjacent pairs of squares available for the second domino.
This violation of the product rule also seems to prevent a recursive definition as $f(2n,k)$ is affected by the arrangement of the first all through to the $(k-1)th$ domino.
The next approach I considered is to determine the number of all possible adjacent pairs on the $2n$ square strip. If we know this value $N$, then the original problem is just $N \choose k$ $k!$.
So how does one determine $N$ ? We might consider the universe $U$ of all pairs that can be formed from $[2n]$ and then exclude the ones $(i, j)$ such that i and j are non-adjacent using the inclusion-exclusion principle $$ |U| - \sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{n} \left| \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i \right|$$
where we define $A_i$ to be the subset of $U$ containing all non-adjacent pairs $(i,j)$ where $i,j \in [2n]$. This is where I'm currently stuck.

We can be clever about this problem. Consider that empty squares are a "white piece", and that all white pieces are identical.
Then, an equivalent formulation of the problem would be "In how many distinct ways can we shuffle $2n-2k$ white pieces and $k$ (distinct) dominoes". Notice that each of these shuffles corresponds to one (and only one) way of arranging the dominoes on our strip, and every arrangement has a corresponding shuffle. So both problems are exactly the same and must have the same answer.
The problem then becomes finding the number of permutations of $2n-2k+k$ objects of which $2n-2k$ are identical. And that is:
$\frac{(2n-2k+k)!}{(2n-2k)!} = \frac{(2n-k)!}{(2n-2k)!}$
EDIT: (kinda of) Finding $N$
Knowing the final answer, it's also possible for us to find the number $N$ you asked about (although I will admit solving the problem in a different way just to calculate $N$ is less than ideal, it's still a fun side product)
Assuming your math checks out, and ${N \choose k}k!$ is in fact the answer for some $N$, we can simply write:
${N\choose k}k! = \frac{(2n-k)!}{(2n-2k!)} \implies \frac{N!}{(N-k)!}k! =  \frac{(2n-k)!}{(2n-2k!)} \implies \frac{N!}{(N-k)!} = \frac{(2n-k)!}{(2n-2k)!}$
So, we should have $N=2n-k$, but even knowing what the value of $N$ should be, I have been unable to find a way to directly compute $N$ before the answer.

Brilliant approach considering permutations of $ 2n−2k+k$ objects. Also I noticed that $N$ as defined in the OP is a bit nonsensical. Why? because some some adjacent pairs are mutually exlcusive. That is why $N$ can only be defined for a given $k$.

Thank you!
On another note, I think you're right about $N$ being weirdly defined in the OP. However, I do think the expression for $N$ in terms of $k$ should be right (even if it's meaning is not what you defined in the OP), as it shows up in the other answer posted in this question.

If you want a simple recursion for $g(k,m)$ (the number of ways to place $k$ indistinguishable dominoes on a strip of length $m$, where $m\ge 2k$), note that either the first square is empty, or the first two squares are occupied by a domino.  So
$$
g(k,m)=g(k,m-1) + g(k-1,m-2).
$$
(If the dominoes are distinguishable, just multiply by $k!$.)
You can then easily check that
$$
g(k,m) = {{m-k}\choose{k}}
$$
satisfies the recursion.
